# Expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before ";" token

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I was planning to merge a motion sensor with blynk app running but this error is stopping me and I don't really know what is going wrong. I did what the tutorial asked me to do but still can't figure out what is the error coming out from the code:

```c
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>

char auth[] = "6Ou9LvxXsYMx162V3Rsij4fmcU-AgOQT";

char ssid[] = "MSI 1251";
char pass[] = "1=A864d0";

volatile boolean pirState = 0; // Initialize the variable with 0 value.


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(D1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D4,OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D4,HIGH);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);

  pinMode(7, OUTPUT); // Initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(2, INPUT);   // Initialize digital pin 2 as an input.
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2),pirResponse,CHANGE ); // This command is used to set PIN 2 in interrupt mode on arduino. pirResponse is the ISR (code that will be executed when interrupt is raised).

}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
}

voidpirResponse() // Function to moniotr the detection motion.
{
  if (pirState==1) // Monitors the status of variable
  {
    pirState=0;  // Makes pirstate to 0 in order to proceed for further process.
    digitalWrite(7,LOW); // If motion not detected then turns OFF the LED which is connected to digital pin 7.
}
  else
  {
    pirState=1;  // Makes pirState to 0 in order to proceed for further process.
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH); // If motion detected then turns ON the LED which is connected to digital pin 7.
  }
}
```

Comment: When error occured (or when you need someone to help you), look at the error message to see which line caused it. I bet it is `voidpirResponse()` in this case, it should be `void pirResponse()`.

Comment: Alright it solved now thanks alot